# Почему не выводится кнопка читать далее в теме wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, функции

Есть [тестовый сайт](http://a-lot-of-money.ru/templates/31/category/photo/) на wordpress с установленной [темой bolid](http://themeforest.net/item/bolid-responsive-news-magazine-and-blog-theme/full_screen_preview/4361177). Не знаю почему, но не выводятся кнопки читать далее, как тут на картинке (можно посмотреть [по ссылке](http://themeforest.net/item/bolid-responsive-news-magazine-and-blog-theme/full_screen_preview/4361177)):
в файле `functions.php` есть такие функции:

```
// Old Shorten Excerpt text for use in theme
function vergo_excerpt($text, $chars = 1620) {
  $text = $text." ";
  $text = substr($text,0,$chars);
  $text = substr($text,0,strrpos($text,' '));
  $text = $text."...";
  return $text;
}

function trim_excerpt($text) {
  return rtrim($text,'[...]');
}
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'trim_excerpt');
function insert_prettyPhoto_rel($content) {
  $pattern = '/<a(.*?)href="(.*?).(bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|png)"(.*?)>/i';
    $replacement = '<a$1href="$2.$3" rel=\'prettyPhoto\'$4>';
  $content = preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $content );
  return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'insert_prettyPhoto_rel' );
```

а сам вывод в файле `archivepost.php`:

```
echo vergo_excerpt( get_the_excerpt(), '260');
```

Пробовал заменять **get_the_excerpt()** на **get_the_content()** и **the_content()**,
играться с количеством символов до вывода - все тщетно: обрезает или по троеточию, или по … или текст до читать далее, а саму кнопку не выводит - что посоветуете?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот этот вывод

```
echo vergo_excerpt( get_the_excerpt(), '260');
```

попробуйте заменить на обычный

```
the_content();
```

Либо измените код функции `vergo_excerpt()` в её предпоследней строке. Склеивайте возвращаемый текст не с троеточием, а со ссылкой на запись

т. е. в functions.php функция будет иметь вид:

```
function vergo_excerpt($text, $chars = 1620) {
  $link = get_the_permalink();
  $text = $text." ";
  $text = substr($text,0,$chars);
  $text = substr($text,0,strrpos($text,' '));
  $text = $text . '<a href="' . $link . '">читать дальше</a>';
  return $text;
}
```

в archive.php вызываете её внутри цикла:

```
if (have_posts()) {
    while(have_posts()) {
        the_post();
        /* ... */
        echo vergo_excerpt(get_the_excerpt(), 260);
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Comment: если меняю на обычный `the_content();`, то обрезается текст до кнопки читать далее, а если добавляю ссылку в функцию `vergo_excerpt`, то она указывает не на конкретный пост, а на страницу записей на которой сейчас и находимся, т.е. не то, что нужно..

Comment: а если передавать `ID` нужного поста в `get_the_permalink()`: `get_the_permalink($post->ID)`?

Comment: вопрос где, в какой функции?

Comment: Обновила ответ. Код проверила у себя - работает. На страницах категорий записи выводятся ограниченным числом символов со ссылкой в конце текста на пост целиком. Если у вас такая конструкция не работает, не могли бы вы привести код из `archive.php`? Есть подозрение, что что-то не так с циклом вывода записей

Comment: спасибо, как после оказалось - такой вывод был только для страниц категорий(архивов), а на главной все выводилось норм с кнопкой читать далее - вот где я ее видел! самый правильное решение поэтому: `<?php the_content('Continue Reading'); ?><a class="mainbutton fr" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php _e('Read More','vergo');?> <i class="icon-circle-arrow-right"></i></a>`